# In Django REST API, should a POST only APIView define a GET method?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to Django and REST APIs in general. I am exposing a data import URL using Django REST framework i.e. /api/data/import.

I currently have an associated APIView that implements a POST method, but returns 405 - Bad Request on a GET as that is the default framework behaviour when GET has not been explicitly implemented.

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) strongly suggests GET should always be implemented, so should I just return an empty 200 response? This also smells a little bit like I am using REST incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: the MDN article, its based on HTTP protocol, rest is different than HTTP, it is simple representational state transfer, the underlying logic is client remembers everything required for the action to be performed by the server. On fulfilling those requirements by the client, the server returns the response and that is it. Implementing get method is your requirement, it will not affect your restful architecture.

Comment: @ArpitGoyal Thanks for your response. So even though Django REST framework uses HTTP responses to communicate, it doesn't need to abide by HTTP protocol? I respect that REST and HTTP protocol are different.

Comment: yes exactly... REST was created by the same guy who created HTTP, so he used the same status codes but defined a different protocol altogether.

Comment: @ArpitGoyal Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to follow those advices you should return a 204 which means "no content" and seems appropriate. There's something so it exists -you can POST to it- but it's empty.

I believe 405 should be fine - there's something there but not with GET.